# ibm notes dialoglist how to get USD as default

Tags: lotus-notes, formula

On a Form I have a dialog list field button. When a user opens this dialog list they can choose a currency which for example is:
"EUR"
"USD"

These currencies I have them in a View and with formula language I add them to the dialog list:

```
SearchKey := @Trim(Adm + "~currencyCode");
Code := @DbLookup("";CurrentServer:DB;View;SearchKey;2);
Code
```

Now when the Form is opened already a default value is selected which is: EUR. I want this to be USD. But how can I do this??

Comment: Please clarify - is the above formula entered into the "Use formula for choices" option for the dialog list field? Or is that the default value formula for the field?

Comment: the formula above is added in to the 'Use formula for choices' options

Answer (score 0):

A dialog list field, like any editable field, can have a default value.
Set this default value to "EUR" and you are done.

Comment: I have already tried using default value, but it takes the one which is from the formula.. So it keeps taking EUR

Comment: I suspect a confusion between  the formula for the default value and the one that populates the list of choices. To help us assist you further, I would suggest you take the following steps : 1) create a brand new form with nothing on it 2) copy-paste the offending field, and nothing else 3) edit the new form as DXL, format the source, copy-paste that source here.

Comment: Also, you need to look at the contents of column 2 in the view that the @DbLookup is targeting. Does it contain only the values EUR and USD (for the documents that match the key), or does it contain values like "EUR|1" and "USD|2"?